# Cleaner way to convert dd-mm-yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have this date as string with me 15-07-2011 which is in the format `dd-mm-yyyy`. I needed to create a `Date` object from this string. So I have to convert the date in `dd-mm-yyyy` to `mm-dd-yyyy` format.

What I did is the following.

```
var myDate = '15-07-2011';
var chunks = myDate.split('-');

var formattedDate = chunks[1]+'-'+chunks[0]+'-'+chunks[2];
```

Now I got the string 07-15-2011 which is in `mm-dd-yyyy` format, and I can pass it to the `Date()` constructor to create a `Date` object. I wish to know if there is any cleaner way to do this.

Comment: @Lime No, I meant cleaner - widely accepted practice.

Comment: Firefox 3.6 does noes not understand "mm-dd-yyyy", use either "mm/dd/yyyy" or "yyyy-mm-dd". I would favor the later, as it's an ISO standard.

Comment: @Sparky Just clarifying, I thought it looked pretty clean as is.  This could be cleaner if your in to regexs `'15-07-2011'.replace(/(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)/,'$2-$1-$3')`

Comment: @Edgar Thanks for pointing out that "mm-dd-yyyy" is not supported in Firefox 3.6. I ended up having the problem in Firefox 5 and was totally confused as the code was working fine in Chrome. Your note helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks very clean as it is.

Comment: All answers were very helpful and assuring. My special thanks goes to Edgar Bonet for his helpful comments all over. I would've selected his as accepted answer if he had answered (no offense meant to Paul Sonier or any other nice ppl who answered/commented. All who answered were helpful). Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Re-arranging chunks of a string is a perfectly "clean" and legitimate way to change a date format.

However, if you're not happy with that (maybe you want to know that the string you're re-arranging is actually a valid date?), then I recommend you look at [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/), which is a full-featured date handling library for Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to DateJS. But probably I should stick to the current way as my requirement is just to convert dd-mm-yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy. Wouldn't want the overhead of another library for just that.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by cleaner

```
var myDate = '15-07-2011';
var chunks = myDate.split('-');
var formattedDate = [chunks[1],chunks[0],chunks[2]].join("-");
```

Some would say this is cleaner, but it does essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
var formattedDate = chunks[1] + '-' + chunks[0] + '-' + chunks.pop();
```

Comment: It looks like you added three characters and a useless function call to me.

Comment: Thanks.., but why would you use pop() when you exactly know the array index and it is not going to change?

Comment: If you don't know the array index and you don't need chunks anymore after that, I find pop mmuch quicker to refer to the last element of the array. If your code is mission critical of course no need for a useless function call like @cbrandolino said.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to you could cut down on some variables.

```
var date = '15-07-2011'.split('-');
date = date[1]+'-'+date[0]+'-'+date[2];
```

If you want a one liner

```
var date = '15-07-2011'.replace(/(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)/,'$2-$1-$3')
```

Comment: Thanks Lime. Regex is not my thing though :)

Comment: Yeah they are pretty ugly ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```
var c = '01-01-2011'.split('-');
var d = new Date(c[2],c[1]-1,c[0]);
```

Comment: +1 as this does not depend on the particular text formats that `new Date()` may accept.

Comment: @Sparky: Because Date objects count months starting at 0 = Jan.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my opinion that your solution is perfectly valid, but if you want something different:

```
var myDate = '15-07-2011';
myDate.split('-').reverse().join('-');
```

Will give you '2011-07-15' which, although not exactly what you asked for, will be parsed properly by `Date`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for parsing, manipulating, and formatting strings named [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

```
var date = moment('15-07-2011', 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
myDate.format("mm-dd-yyyy");
```

Comment: 'try'?? And when did programming get based on trying random things?
`#format` will only work if the `Date.prototype` has been augmented with such a method.

Comment: `myDate` is not even a Date: it's a String! Then this hypothetical `format()` method should be in the `String.prototype`, which makes even less sense.